# Clock Buffer enabled after probing

Tags: clock, crystal, buffer

I have clock buffer(NB3H83905C) on my development board. Pin 1 and 16 are interfaced to 25Mhcrystal(250 ABMM G3C) pin 3 and 1. After power on, I don't see the clock on pin 1. When I touch pin 16 using oscilloscope probe, I can see the clock on pin 1. What's the  reason for this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: It means the circuit has problems starting up and touching it with the oscilloscope probe makes it start up. Please link to which exact crystal you bought, simply the model series or datasheet for a series of crystals is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Here is the link: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/abracon-llc/ABMM-25-000MHZ-B2-T/675356?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKwGY4FoCcBGAbO5OB2AJiALoC%2BQA

Comment: Crystal itself should be compatible. And the two load caps, which value/type caps they are? What about PCB layout? Are you using 1x or 10x scope probes?

Comment: caps are 33p SMD.  There is no switch in probe. So, probe is 1x. The clock is working on some boards. But not all.